How to add additional existing tag in answer of a question to find it in search result?
Sometime it is needed to add additional existing tags in an answer, other than what are specified by the OP in his/her/their question, when the answer includes additional data sections related to other existing tags, so that other users who are searching additional tags can find the answer.
In an answer, at bottom, can a user specify few existing other tags by specifying the tag name/word like these ?[tag:existingTag] [tag:tag-info]
I had to use <code> ... </code> block for above line during writing, to show the 3rd-braced words to readers, but if i don't use this "code" block, & specify above words as plain-text, then it becomes as shown below:existingtag tag-info
Will above formatted tag words allow other users related to those additionally added tags, to search+find the answer in search result ?

Answers in tags are not used for indexing, so only reasons I can think of where "Sometime it is needed to add additional existing tags in an answer" would be some per-site conventions (e.g., [law.se] has a convention where people can add answers for various countries with the country tag mentioned at the top of the answer, but naturally it doesn't do anything for searching that simple text doesn't)

Hi muru, changed the top/title question little bit, but main objective of my question was different than your liked question. my original objective remained same, to allow+find the answer in a tag related search result (see the last line). If added tags can allow the answer to show up in search result, then thats sufficient & purpose of tagging has completed. But if the answer would still not-show-up in search result, then no point of adding tags, but the usefulness can come later in future when/if such tagged answer are also included+displayed in search result.

Are you making a [tag:feature-request]? Otherwise the answer remains the same: there's no extra benefit to linking a tag in an answer.

Thanks for informing the convention used in "Law" site. Adding tags in 1st/top line is better for reader & search-engines, as reader can understand easily what area/subject of context is included in that answer. I thought "answer"/"comment" etc cannot add any tagging, so i suggested to allow adding tags atleast in bottom . But sorry to learn now, that, even if tags are added in answer, its not indexed, so the answer will not show up in search result.

muru, your knowledgeable comments/responses, have just turned my question into a feature-request as well, as now there is no way to add the tags in a "answer" indexed+findable over search result. So now reader can click on tag to search other related "question". adding a feature-request tag for feature-request.
